# Error when checking model input: expected convolution2d_input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 32, 3)

Tags: deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I want to train a deep network starting with the following layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
```

using

```
history = model.fit_generator(get_training_data(),
                samples_per_epoch=1, nb_epoch=1,nb_val_samples=5,
                verbose=1,validation_data=get_validation_data()
```

with the following generator:

```
def get_training_data(self):
     while 1:
        for i in range(1,5):
            image = self.X_train[i]
            label = self.Y_train[i]
            yield (image,label)
```

(validation generator looks similar).

During training, I get the error:

```
Error when checking model input: expected convolution2d_input_1 to have 4 
dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 32, 3)
```

How can that be, with a first layer

```
 model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
```

?

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: Just add np.asarray() around the list of the image data. This would adjust the list provided by you to it's expected size. Even if you are predicting on a single image data enclose it within a list and np.asarray().

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The input shape you have defined is the shape of a single sample. The model itself expects some array of samples as input (even if its an array of length 1).

Your output really should be 4-d, with the 1st dimension to enumerate the samples. i.e. for a single image you should return a shape of (1, 32, 32, 3).

You can find more information [here](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) under "Convolution2D"/"Input shape"

**Edit**: Based on Danny's comment below, if you want a batch size of 1, you can add the missing dimension using this:

```
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
```

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia You should change x_ip_shape in the same manner.

Comment: changing the input size causes the error to change to "Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5".
Anyone have some help ?

Comment: use `image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0))` to add an extra dimension

Answer (score 6):

It is as simple as to Add one dimension, so I was going through the tutorial taught by Siraj Rawal on CNN Code Deployment tutorial, it was working on his terminal, but the same code was not working on my terminal, so I did some research about it and solved, I don't know if that works for you all. Here I have come up with solution;

Unsolved code lines which gives you problem:

```
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    print(x_train.shape)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
```

Solved Code:

```
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    print(x_train.shape)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
```

Please share the feedback here if that worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

Probably **very trivial**, but I solved it by just converting the input to *numpy array*.

For the neural network architecture,

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation="relu", input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
```

When the input was,

```
    n_train = len(train_y_raw)
    train_X = [train_X_raw[:,:,:,i] for i in range(n_train)]
    train_y = [train_y_raw[i][0] for i in range(n_train)]
```

I got the error,[image]

But when I changed it to,

```
   n_train = len(train_y_raw)
   train_X = np.asarray([train_X_raw[:,:,:,i] for i in range(n_train)])
   train_y = np.asarray([train_y_raw[i][0] for i in range(n_train)])
```

It fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error while working with mnist data set, looks like a problem with the dimensions of X_train. I added another dimension and it solved the purpose.

X_train, X_test, \
y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_reshaped,
                                  y_labels,
                                  train_size = 0.8,
                                  random_state = 42)

X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,28, 28, 1)

X_test = X_test.reshape(-1,28, 28, 1)

Answer (score 2):

You should simply apply the following transformation to your input data array.

```
input_data = input_data.reshape((-1, image_side1, image_side2, channels))
```

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how you actually order your data,if its on a channel first basis then you should reshape your data:
x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],channel,width,height)

if its channel last:
x_train=s_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],width,height,channel)

Answer (score 0):

yes, it accepts the tuple of four arguments, 
if you have Number of training Images(or whatever)=6000,
image size=28x28
and a grayscale image
you'll have parameters as (6000,28,28,1)

the last argument is 1 for greyscale and 3 for color images.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, non of the answers worked for me. After a lot of debugging I found out that the size of one image was smaller than `32`. This leads to a broken array with wrong dimensions and the above mentioned error.

To solve the problem, make sure that *all* images have the correct dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1,28, 28, 1)   #Reshape for CNN -  should work!!
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1,28, 28, 1)
history_cnn = cnn.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Output:

> Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
>   Epoch 1/5
>   60000/60000 [==============================] - 157s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0981 - acc: 0.9692 - val_loss: 0.0468 - val_acc: 0.9861
>   Epoch 2/5
>   60000/60000 [==============================] - 157s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0352 - acc: 0.9892 - val_loss: 0.0408 - val_acc: 0.9879
>   Epoch 3/5
>   60000/60000 [==============================] - 159s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0242 - acc: 0.9924 - val_loss: 0.0291 - val_acc: 0.9913
>   Epoch 4/5
>   60000/60000 [==============================] - 165s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0181 - acc: 0.9945 - val_loss: 0.0361 - val_acc: 0.9888
>   Epoch 5/5
>   60000/60000 [==============================] - 168s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0142 - acc: 0.9958 - val_loss: 0.0354 - val_acc: 0.9906

Comment: Describe what you did and why please.