# save predicted images to a folder

Tags: generative-adversarial-network, image-formats

I'm using model.fit_generator() to predict images. i keep on receiving the following error:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_29_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (224, 224, 3)
I'm trying to save the predicted images to a folder.

following is my code:

```
data_list = []
batch_index = 0

while batch_index <= train_generator.batch_index:
    data = next(train_generator)
    data_list.append(data[0])
    batch_index = batch_index + 1

 for i in range(batch_index):
     for j in range(batch_size):
         predicted[i][j]= model.predict(data_list[i] [j])
         plt.imsave(os.path.join(path,'new_image'+ str(i)+ str(j)+ "_AE_.tiff"), predicted[i][j])
```

what is the problem with the shape??
thanks

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41595178/6818619) might help.

Comment: It was helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

following is how i solved the problem:

```
path='the data folder'

data_list = [] 
batch_index = 0
predicted=[]
n= len(train_generator)

while batch_index <= train_generator.batch_index:
    data = train_generator.next()
    data_list.append(data[0])
    batch_index = batch_index + 1

data_array = np.array(data_list, dtype= float)

    
predicted=model.predict(data_array)

for i in range(n):
    plt.imsave(os.path.join(path,'new_image'+ str(i)+"_AE.tiff"), predicted[i,])
```